# How to create custom parameter prompt dialog for Crystal Reports in Java?

Tags: java, crystal-reports

I'm literally just starting with Crystal Reports so please bear with me.

I've been following the tutorials from here -> http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-31247 and I'm doing my crystal project from Eclipse using Java.

Now, once we have parameters, I know from reading around that the parameter prompt dialog gets displayed automatically. What I'm trying to achieve is something similar to what's discussed in this (http://scn.sap.com/thread/1212239) thread - How can you get the values from the prompt dialog BEFORE the report is run?

Reading around, I know we can set parameters programmatically via the setting of the parameters using a collection of Field objects. Then it's suggested that one look into the Crystal SDK (http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/BusinessObjectsXIR2/en/devsuite.htm) to create your own custom forms so that you can extract the values at will. However, the SDK more or less says the use of JSF, another technology I'm not familiar with...

So again, is there a way to get the parameters typed in by the user in the parameter prompt dialog? If not, what's the best way (even to just start) to create my own form?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple JSP page with a form that redirects the form to the generated JSP page works.